# More efficient way to send a request than JSON to deployed tensorflow model in Sagemaker?

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained a tf.estimator based TensorFlow model in Sagemaker and deployed it and it works fine.

But I can only send requests to it in JSON format. I need to send some big input tensors and this seems very inefficient and also quickly breaks InvokeEndpoints 5MB request limit.

Is it possible to use a more effective format against the tensorflow serving based endpoint?

I tried sending a protobuf based request:

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow.serving import Model 
from sagemaker.tensorflow.tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2 
from sagemaker.tensorflow.predictor import tf_serializer, tf_deserializer

role = 'xxx'

model = Model('s3://xxx/tmp/artifacts/sagemaker-tensorflow-scriptmode-xxx/output/model.tar.gz', role)

predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c5.xlarge', endpoint_name='test-endpoint')

# this predictor has json serializer, make a new one pred = 

RealTimePredictor('test-endpoint', serializer=tf_serializer, deserializer=tf_deserializer)

req = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()

req.inputs['instances'].CopyFrom(tf.make_tensor_proto(np.zeros((4, 36, 64)), shape=(4, 36, 64)))

predictor.predict(req)
```

Which results in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModelError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-5ba7f281bd0d> in <module>()
----> 1 predictor.predict(req)

~/anaconda3/envs/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py in predict(self, data, initial_args)
     76 
     77         request_args = self._create_request_args(data, initial_args)
---> 78         response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
     79         return self._handle_response(response)
     80 

~/anaconda3/envs/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
    355                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
    356             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
--> 357             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
    358 
    359         _api_call.__name__ = str(py_operation_name)

~/anaconda3/envs/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
    659             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
    660             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
--> 661             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
    662         else:
    663             return parsed_response

ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (415) from model with message "{"error": "Unsupported Media Type: application/octet-stream"}".
```

Is JSON the only available query format for deployed TensorFlow models ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at batch transform? If you don't need actually an HTTPS endpoint, this might solve your problem:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-batch-transform.html

Comment: With batch jobs you can disable the request size limit so that works.

  
Still JSON is probably one of the worst transfer formats for large dense arrays.


  
AWS support has suggested creating a custom input_fn - if I can pass this to the tensorflow model exporter and it gets picked up by sagemakers serving container you could use any input format you want.

Comment: That's good feedback, thank you. What kind of input format would you like to use instead?

Comment: I'm looking at protobuf since that' sort of built in. Thanks to AWS support I'll look at adding a custom input_fn to the model which would simplify a lot of input related stuff for us.