# TensorFlow Serving send data as b64 instead of Numpy Array

Tags: python, image, base64, tensorflow-serving, amazon-sagemaker

I have a TensorFlow Serving container in a SageMaker endpoint. I'm able to take a batch of images as a Numpy array and get back predictions like this:

```
import numpy as np
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.predictor import json_serializer, json_deserializer

image = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(1,128,128,3)).astype(np.float32)    
image = {'instances': image}
image = json_serializer(image)

request_args = {}
request_args['Body'] = image
request_args['EndpointName'] = endpoint_name
request_args['ContentType'] = 'application/json'
request_args['Accept'] = 'application/json'

# works successfully
response = sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
response_body = response['Body']
predictions = json_deserializer(response_body, response['ContentType'])
```

The size of the `request_args` payload is large doing it this way. I'm wondering, is there a way to send this in a more compressed format?

I've tried experimenting with `base64` and `json.dumps`, but can't get past `Invalid argument: JSON Value: ...` errors. Not sure if this isn't supported or if I'm just doing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've talked to AWS support about this (see [More efficient way to send a request than JSON to deployed tensorflow model in Sagemaker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54090270/more-efficient-way-to-send-a-request-than-json-to-deployed-tensorflow-model-in-s)).

They suggest that it is possible to pass in a custom input_fn that will be used by the serving container where one can unpack a compressed format (such as protobuf).

I'll be testing this soon and hopefully this stuff works since it would add a lot of flexibility to the input processing.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it's possible. Would this input_fn go in the serve script of a BYO container, somewhere else, or does this go along with Script Mode? Please let me know if you make any progress. I see input_fn here: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container/blob/master/src/tf_container/serve.py but still trying to parse how it works

Comment: I was told to put the custom input_fn in the train script. https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_python.rst#endpoint-prediction-request-handling

Comment: Got it working with json serialized base64 encoded strings, thanks. Now if I can just get compressed protobuff working

Comment: Could you post an example of the base64 solution?

Comment: @Austin could you post your solution?